# Meaning of 'Gift from the Storm God' achievement in Civilization 6

Tags: achievements, civilization-6

In Civilization VI, you can receive an achievement called 'Gift from the Storm God' if you receive a strategic resource from the City-State of Hattusa. I've learned that Hattusa was the capital of the ancient Hittite Empire in modern-day Turkey, but still don't understand the allusion. Does anyone know what the achievement title is referring to?

Anecdotally, the city (as it's thought to have looked) was pretty awesome in real life:
[image]

Comment: It could be just the way the developers worded the achievement.  I can't find anything suggesting a relation between gifts or giving and the storm god [_Tarhun_](https://glitternight.com/2014/04/22/hittite-mythology-the-top-deities/).

Comment: @TimmyJim me neither, I thought maybe it as a reference to some esoteric piece of sci-fi literature or something. It at least begs the question, why that city-state for the achievement?

Comment: From Wikipedia, `"Storm gods" were prominent in the Hittite pantheon.` I don't think there's anything more to read into it than that.

Answer (score 1):

**Hattusa**

[Hattusa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hattusa) was a city in [Anatolia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anatolia) (name for the region known today as central Turkey). The city was destroyed and rebuilt a few times, for example the city was destroyed by the king Anitta in 18th century B.C. who claimed it was accursed and then it was later rebuilt by one of the first Hittite kings. As such I find it surprising we know so much about the city, apparently other civilizations such as the Assyrians kept records on the city.

**Its Temple(s)**

"Gift of the Storm God" references the fact that in the "Lower City" of Hattusa there was enormous temple referred to as the "Temple of the Storm God". Apparently the city had many temples (31 stated in this [reference](http://www.biblicalarchaeology.org/daily/ancient-cultures/ancient-near-eastern-world/the-last-days-of-hattusa/)) but this temple towered over all of them.

I suggest reading more of this [reference](http://www.biblicalarchaeology.org/daily/ancient-cultures/ancient-near-eastern-world/the-last-days-of-hattusa/), I found it to be very interesting and considering you've asked this question I think you would find it interesting as well (assuming you don't already know it of course).

Answer (score 0):

I only have anecdotal evidence to this claim, but it may be a reference to the Japanese manga, *Red River*.

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_River_(manga)):

> Red River is about a fifteen-year-old Japanese girl named Yuri Suzuki, who is magically transported to Hattusa, the capital of the Hittite Empire in Anatolia. She was summoned by Queen Nakia who means to use Yuri as a human sacrifice. Yuri's blood is the key element needed in placing a curse upon the princes of the land so that they will perish, leaving Nakia's son as the sole heir to the throne.

And according to this [web blog](https://silverstarwings.wordpress.com/category/red-river-manga/), the storm god was to be the recipient of the sacrifice:

> The queen Nakia is trying to kill Yuri for her son succession to the
>   throne making him the next emperor of the Hittites, by using Yuri
>   blood for a curse by sacrifice it the god Teshub (the god of the
>   storm).

Not sure how that connects to a strategic resource (although I guess it could be 'Yuri blood' since placing her son on the throne is certainly a strategic action), but it at least connects Hattusa and the 'Storm God'.

Comment: why is this getting downvotes?